# Can anyone tell me query to carry forward balance to next day in oracle?

Tags: oracle, etl, sqlplus

Here we have credit and debit data for two dates. Please tell me the query to carry forward balance from one transaction date to another.

sample table:

```
TRANS_DATE    CREDIT      DEBIT
--------- ---------- ----------
24-SEP-18       2500        400
24-SEP-18                   200
24-SEP-18        500
30-SEP-18        400       1200
30-SEP-18        400
```

Expected output output:

```
 TRANS_DATE    BALANCE
---------  ----------
24-SEP-18       2400
30-SEP-18       2000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the [analytical `SUM` function](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions004.htm#SQLRF06174).

First aggregate `CREDIT` and `DEBIT` on a day level (using GROUP BY) see the subquery below.

Than use the analytical `SUM` function

```
sum(CREDIT - DEBIT) over (order by TRANS_DATE) as balance
```

You ommited the windowing_clause, which means you sums all row up to current row in the given order. See the relevant part from the documentation below.

> If you omit the windowing_clause entirely, then the default is RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW.

Note that you calculate the balance globally, so you don't use the `PARTITION BY` clause. You'll do so if you consider teh balance e.g. on an account basis.

Query

```
with day_bal as (
select trans_date, sum(nvl(credit,0)) credit, sum(nvl(debit,0)) debit from bal
group by trans_date)
select 
TRANS_DATE, CREDIT, DEBIT,
sum(CREDIT - DEBIT) over (order by TRANS_DATE) as balance
from day_bal
order by 1;
```

gives

```
TRANS_DATE              CREDIT      DEBIT    BALANCE
------------------- ---------- ---------- ----------
24-09-2018 00:00:00       3000        600       2400
30-09-2018 00:00:00        800       1200       2000
```

Comment: @ Marmite Bomber- This is what i was looking for, Thank you so much for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can sum the credits and the debits and subtract the latter from the former:

```
SELECT   trans_date, SUM(credit) - SUM(debit) AS balance
FROM     mytable
GROUP BY trans_date
```

Comment: @ Mureunik - right sir, but this quiry will give us balance for each date, however I want a quiry which can add balance of one trans_date to another so on, just like our bank statment so that at the last date of month i will get total balance remaining in my account.